# How to remove all spaces after <br /> tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to remove all spaces after all `<br />` tags from a entire text.

`trim()` doesn't work.

```
$str = "something<br /> ";
$str = preg_replace('/(<br(?: \\/)?>/\s+/', '', $str);
```

output: "something" instead of `"something "`

I don't want to remove `<br />` or replace for space.

Comment: You want to remove <br /> tag or space?

Comment: `$str = "something<br />";` will output `something` with a line break but not `something ` with a space

Comment: where the space in your this example: `something<br />`

Comment: when i make the request from db i see a space after <br />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes space characters and tabs. Note that `\s` removes ALL whitespace characters including newlines, so you might have a very long line of code to read if you used it instead of the space and `\t` character.

```
$str = preg_replace('!(\<br ?/?\>)([ ]|\t)+!i', '<br />', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `str_replace()` if you KNOW there is ONLY one space (literally a space character) that trails a break tag to be removed.

Otherwise, regex is the better tool to use for the task.

I recommend this pattern: `~<br(?: /)?>\K\s+~i`

- use a pattern delimiter that is not a forward slash to avoid using a backslash to escape the forward slash inside the pattern.
- `<br(?: /)?>` will match `<br>` and `<br />`
- `\K` will restart the fullstring match -- this eliminates the need for a capture group. Always avoid using capture groups if possible, they cost extra steps and will slow down your pattern.  Because the break tag is not being matched, an empty string is all that is required for the replacement value.
- `\s+` will match one or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines) that trail each break tag
- the `i` flag / pattern modifier will match break tags whether they are written in uppercase, lowercase, or a mixture of the two.

Here is a Pattern&Replacement Demo Link: https://regex101.com/r/1gMus1/1

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8uBa4))

```
<?php
$string='This is a space after a <br> break.
This is 2 spaces after a <br>  break.
This is a tab after a <br>  break.
This is a newline after a <br>
break';

var_export(str_replace(['<br> ','<br /> '],['<br>','<br />'],$string));  // if you KNOW there is only one space

echo "\n\n";

var_export(preg_replace('~<br(?: /)?>\K\s+~i','',$string));  // if you want to remove all spaces, tabs, newlines
?>
```

Your original pattern was close, but it had a couple of flaws:

```
    /(<br(?: \\/)?>/\s+/
//   ^             ^-- an unexpected, pattern-crippling forward slash
//   |-- the start of a capture group, but no closing parenthesis
```

p.s. for the record `/<br[^>]*>\K\s+/i/` is slightly faster but less literal about the br tag syntax.

If you are being very literal about "spaces" and don't want to match newline characters or tabs, then this will do nicely: `~<br(?: /)?>\K +~i`

Answer (score -1):

Change regex to

```
preg_replace("(something<br \/>)\s*", "$1", $str)
```

this will replace your string to contain `something<br />` only.

Comment: i wanna replace only spaces after <br />
like `"something<br />       "` to `"something<br />"`

Comment: i think people are misunderstand me i need replace `<br />` to `<br />` in a entire text

Comment: Of course we'll misunderstand you. You wanna replace some piece of string with itself?? You can't explain yourself my friend. You say you wanna replace "<br />" with "<br />" which are both the same!

Comment: not really i said i wanna replace `<br />blank space` with `<br />`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$str = "something<br />";
$output = str_replace("<br />", "", $str);
echo $output;
```

If you want to avoid the space only, than try this:

```
$output = trim($str);
```

Comment: it doesn't work after i use this tag it adds a space when i request from db

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
$string = str_replace("<br /> ", "<br />", $string);
```

Comment: it didn't work.. i don't know exactly is happening... i copy and paste a text in a textarea then i put some br tags to insert it on db when i request it in update page it comes with spaces after br tag